# How to atomically change / rotate log file every minute?

Tags: logs

I've got a legacy app that is generating a huge lot of logs message.
I'd like to be able to rotate the file every minute (or so) but without loosing / truncating any message.
The app is not able to change of file by itself so I need to do it externally.
Surfing the net I've seen a lot of suggestion to use `cp` followed by a `cat /dev/null` but since my app is generating almost a continuous flow of messages some messages are lost during the process.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: You can also rotate the log file when file size reaches a specific limit

Comment: A side comment: `cat /dev/null` is a popular still urban legend. It can be easily replaced by `:` or even nothing, given the fact it is a no-op.

Comment: size doesn't matter in my case : I need it to rotate as frequently as possible to save auditing logs remotely.

Comment: @jlliagre "easily replaced by" meaning: ": is faster by a factor of 200" (on my system)

Comment: why not just `logrotate -f config` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the log file a FIFO (`man mkfifo`) and put a process on the reading side which separates its input into files of limited size.

```
mkfifo /path/to/logfifo.app_xy
split ... </path/to/logfifo.app_xy &
/bad/app
```

Comment: Nice start but I'm looking for a complete solution. Not that yours is bad, but I was very surpised that in 2013 the minimum rotation time for every one is `daily` like in `logrotate`. Everybody is talking about big data, auditing and so on, but I feel like the only one needing much frequent rotation ...

Comment: @Cerber "complete solution" meaning what? logrotate can rotate by size, too, if I remember correctly.

Comment: ooooooops, you meant THE `split` unix core command. Sorry @HaukeLaging I've read your answer too fast. I'll check that on my app

Comment: Hi Hauke Laging, I went on with a couple of tests but I can't get it right :   `split` is not fit for time-based split, so I've thought to 'crontab' it. But I started with a simpler solution : I wrote a perl script that outputs in the fifo each numbers from 0 to 10000 with a 100ms sleep. I ran this in background and did a `head` on it to gather the first bytes just to check that two `head` calls would not break the sequence ... unfortunalty I got a `[1]+  Broken pipe             perl script.pl >log` at the first `head`. Therefore I think `split` would not work. What am I missing ?

Comment: @Cerber You probably did something like `head log; head log`. Indeed, the first `head` closes the FIFO then. You need a wrapper around the processes which read from the FIFO: `{head log; head log;}` or `exec 3<log; head <&3; head <&3`

Comment: @Cerber I guess someone listened and now logrotate is hourly, and according to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/480551/logrotate-not-rotating-file-after-file-size-exceeds-the-limit) you can set it to whatever interval you want, with a file in cron.d with this `*/10  *  *  *  *   root    /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: Yes, time flies :) indeed logrotate has greatly improved

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) tool can handle this.

Comment: `logrotate` needs at least a little support from the app, due to the way files work in Unix.  If the log file is renamed without notifying the app in some way, the app will continue to write to the renamed file, rather than starting to write to a new file with the old name.  `man 8 logrotate` and note the "postrotate" command in the examples.

Comment: beside, `logrotate` minimum is `daily` ... which is very far from what I want to achieve

Comment: Actually you can force rotation depending on the file size. But it is true that you need either the application's help or the restart it for the log to be rotated.

Comment: @Cerber you can make it hourly

Comment: Hi @Sentient, it was not the case back in 2013 (or at least neither of us figured it out). Thanks for the comment! for the others : `hourly Log files are rotated every hour. Note that usually logrotate is configured to be run by cron daily. You have to change this configuration and run logrotate hourly to be able to really rotate logs hourly.`

Comment: To add to other historical comment about `postrotate`, there is an option called `copytruncate` which ensures the older file is not renamed, but content is copied to new file and old one is truncated. With this, no extra support or restart is needed from application. - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/646903